# Why does Daryl have a red cord tied on his leg?

Tags: the-walking-dead

I've noticed in the early episodes of S10 that Daryl has a red shoelace or similar tied around one leg. Maybe it was there in S9 but I don't *recall* it being a long term addition.

[image]

Is there a backstory to this, or is it just a bit of string holding his clothes together that appeared at some point?

Comment: If memory serves, he wears ties around his ankles to prevent "chigger bites" (the show actor actually got bitten a few times) and the one around his knee is to prevent his trousers from getting caught on his motorbike chain